# Can I persist an http connection (or other data) across Flask requests?

Tags: python, http, flask

I'm working on a Flask app which retrieves the user's XML from the myanimelist.net API ([sample](http://myanimelist.net/malappinfo.php?u=doomcat55&status=all&type=anime)), processes it, and returns some data. The data returned can be different depending on the Flask page being viewed by the user, but the initial process (retrieve the XML, create a User object, etc.) done before each request is always the same.

Currently, retrieving the XML from myanimelist.net is the bottleneck for my app's performance and adds on a good 500-1000ms to each request. Since all of the app's requests are to the myanimelist server, I'd like to know if there's a way to persist the http connection so that once the first request is made, subsequent requests will not take as long to load. I don't want to cache the entire XML because the data is subject to frequent change.

Here's the general overview of my app:

```
from flask import Flask
from functools import wraps
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


def get_xml(f): 
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap():
        # Get the XML before each app function
        r = requests.get('page_from_MAL') # Current bottleneck
        user = User(data_from_r) # User object
        response = f(user)
        return response
    return wrap


@app.route('/one')
@get_xml
def page_one(user_object):
    return 'some data from user_object'


@app.route('/two')
@get_xml
def page_two(user_object):
    return 'some other data from user_object'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

So is there a way to persist the connection like I mentioned? Please let me know if I'm approaching this from the right direction.

Comment: why dont you distribute the get_xml with to task handler that will run the process in the background such as Celery?

Comment: Wouldn't that return stale results in the same manner as caching? Is that unavoidable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you aren't approaching this from the right direction because you place your app too much as a proxy of myanimelist.net.

What happens when you have 2000 users? Your app end up doing tons of requests to myanimelist.net, and a mean user could definitely DoS your app (or use it to DoS myanimelist.net).

This is a much cleaner way IMHO :

- Server side :

  - Create a websocket server (ex: https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/example/server.py)
  - When a user connects to the websocket server, add the client to a list, remove it from the list on disconnect.
  - For every connected users, do frequently check myanimelist.net to get the associated xml (maybe lower the frequence the more online users you get)
  - for every xml document, make a diff with your server local version, and send that diff to the client using the websocket channel (assuming there is a diff).
- Client side :

  - on receiving diff : update the local xml with the differences.
  - disconnect from websocket after n seconds of inactivity + when disconnected add a button on the interface to reconnect

I doubt you can do anything much better assuming myanimelist.net doesn't provide a "push" API.

Comment: Just to clarify - only update for connected users (when changes are found), and do so at fixed intervals? Where would the "local" XML (between updates) be stored between user requests, in the cache?

Comment: yes, only update for connected users at fixed interfals. And you could store the xml in RAM between updates, or on the disk, but yes it's some kind of caching.